# Changing control properties using BasedOn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have  a UserControl with some buttons. I need to change the background colour of the buttons but retain all other properties and colours such as mouseover events

I've used the following code which I hoped would define `UniqueButton1` based on `{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"` but change the background property to define my own colours

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Detail"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="800" BorderBrush="#FF5380E7" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style  x:Key="UniqueButton1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"  >
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF896CE" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF788C7" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF570BB" Offset="0.5" />
                     <GradientStop Color="#FFF353AE" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Height="30" Width="800">
        <Button Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,0,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Click="b_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStretch="SemiCondensed" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource UniqueButton1}" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="423,0,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Click="b_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStretch="SemiCondensed" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It kind of works, in that I get the background colours the way I need, but `UniqueButton1` which I've defined in `<UserControl.Resources>` is not based on the other default button2 with no style changes applied. Eg, the background, colours, animation speeds etc are all different

Perhaps it's because I'm also applying a theme?

My question is either
1. How do I define a resource that is based on a default `button2` with a theme applied?
or
2. How do I get all of the properties of button2 with the theme applied so I can build my own style?

It's been suggested I may need to build my own style, which is fine. But I need to match the behaviour of the default themed button except for the background property - if I can't see how it's made up it seems a bit of a catch22.

EDIT: To clarify things

[image]

[image]

These two images show 3 buttons, you can see the mousover for button3 is orange and blue for button2. What you can't see is that the animation speed is also different. Essentially I want my button to look like button1 in the rest state and button3 on mouseover whilst retaining the button3 animation speed and other properties. Button2 is what I'm getting using basedon with no further properties changed.

Button3 is produced with no resources and XAML

```
<Button Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Click="button_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStretch="SemiCondensed"/>
```

Button2 is produced using

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style  x:Key="TEST1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"  >
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button Style="{StaticResource TEST1}" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Click="button_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStretch="SemiCondensed"/>
```

Button1 is produced using

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style  x:Key="UniqueButton1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"  >
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF896CE" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF788C7" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF570BB" Offset="0.5" />
                     <GradientStop Color="#FFF353AE" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

<Button Style="{StaticResource UniqueButton1}" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Click="button_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStretch="SemiCondensed" />
```

So obviously button 1 and 2 are not based on button3 which is what I want. I want to clone button3 properties and ONLY change the background to pink.

Comment: So you are saying that the the `UniqueButton1` style modifies the background of the default WPF button instead of modifying the background of your theme's button style?

Comment: @Jay - I've updated my Q to try an make things a bit clearer

Comment: Basically, you have a theme for your buttons and you want to extend the default style for your button 1 and 2? I don't understand. You also mentioned you want to inherit the button1's in all state and mouseover on button3.

Comment: B3 is a themed button, I want to retain all properties of B3 EXCEPT the background which instead of being grey (B3 bottom Right pic) I want it pink like B1. B2 is only there to show when I attempt to clone B3 it's not B3. Therefore, B1 is pink but all properties are not themed like B3 - B1 & B2 change to blue on mouseover and not orange. How do I clone B3 which is themed and make background pink OR how do I extract ALL properties (mouseover, animation speed etc) from B3 to rebuild a style to match B3 except pink background?

Comment: Another thought - Is it because the `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}` is using Expressionblend Button default whereas my usercontrol is inheriting the themed Button? Ie B2 is expressionblend & B3 is themed. How can I specifically state which default Button is used in `{x:Type Button}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `BaseButton` from `x:Type` to a named one and then set it's `name` on others `BasedOn`, that should do the trick.